# Apache Camel equivalent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, pop3, apache-camel

Is there an equivalent to Apache Camel in Rails ?!

I'm creating an application that needs to "listen" to messages from one source (for example: email (POP3)) and sends them to another source (for example: logfile or email (using smtp)).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a complete equivalent to Apache Camel. But, to just listen for mails from a POP3 server and send to another source, try the [mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) gem

EDIT: You should also look at [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) gem

Comment: Good answer. But i'm looking for something that handles more than just emails.

Comment: Also looks like Apache Camel already supports [Ruby](http://camel.apache.org/ruby.html)

Comment: Yeah but it's still a java framework. You can only use Ruby code inside a java framework. I'm looking for something like 'apache_camel' gem.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there are no ports of Apache Camel to other languages, including ruby (but others as well, there was a question about .net recently). However, you can use Apache Camel with your application. You can treat Camel as an independent daemon that you need to configure and you can do that conveniently via xml. If you need some of your ruby code to be invoked during processing you can use the Camel org.jruby:jruby support. It may be less than ideal, but it works well. To interact with external systems Camel supports a large number of protocols already (including the ones you mentioned), but one could plug in her own.

Given Camel's support for many languages, protocols and data formats, I doubt anybody will go through the significant effort of porting it to other languages, but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look at [Llama](https://github.com/skyfallsin/llama).

They are in an early stage, but seems like they are going to build "an integration-framework on top of EventMachine that helps with tying together various backend services", which is what Camel is.

Comment: Looks cool. But this project is definitely not an early stage project. The last commit was 3 years ago.

Comment: Good point, I didn't look on commits. However, it just means we need to build our own Camel in Ruby ;)